# When does symfony call loadUserByUsername()?

Tags: php, symfony

Under what circumstances does the Symfony security component call `loadUserByUsername()`?

Is it just on login? If so, is it safe to complete lengthy/login-specific tasks within `loadUserByUsername()`?

For example, rest the lastLogin date against a user's profile, or refresh the user's profile from a web-service.

I have experimented by updating the lastLogin date in the `loadUserByUsername()` method and it does not seem to update on each page load. I could not seem to find the information in either the Symfony API documentation or the Book on the Symfony website.

(I'm using Symfony 2.5, but if your answer varies within the 2.x series, please elaborate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the best solution for what you want to achieve would be use `security.interactive_login` event. It's fired just after succesful login.

Event handler definition:

```
last_login_listener:
    class: Namespace\LastLoginListener
    tags: 
        - { name: kernel.event_listener, event: security.interactive_login, method: logLastLogin }
```

Listener:

```
use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Event\InteractiveLoginEvent;

class LastLoginListener
{
    public function logLastLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        // do what you have to do
    }
}
```

Comment: Be warned, though! It doesn't handle "implicit" logins (such as programmatically setting a `UsernamePasswordToken` inside of a controller or through a 3rd party bundle like `FOSUserBundle` - they login password resets and user confirmations implicitly.)

Comment: Yep,good point. It's like the name says "interactive" login only.

Comment: I assume sso-based logins, like oAuth or openID logins do not count as "interactive"?

Comment: It seems to me that the answer is no. But probably it depends on library you use. Frankly speaking I'm not sure, you have to check it by yourself.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your help. I will have a play and see what I come up with.

Comment: An OpenID login using FpOpenIdBundle fires `security.interactive_login`, and I know FOSUserBundle have their own events, so this looks like a solid method. It would still be great to know under what circumstances `loadUserByUsername()` can be called just for completeness.